# If I multiclass a Wizard and a Sorcerer with Arcane Bloodline, can I choose a familiar for both?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, sorcerer, familiars

If I multiclass a [Wizard](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizARD/#Arcane_Bond_Ex_or_Sp) and a Sorcerer with [Arcane Bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/arcane-bloodline/), can I choose a familiar for both?

Or can I have a familiar from one class and a bonded object from the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Arcane Bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/arcane-bloodline/):

> Arcane Bond (Su): At 1st level, you gain an arcane bond, as a wizard equal to your sorcerer level. **Your sorcerer levels stack with any wizard levels you possess when determining the powers of your familiar or bonded object.** Once per day, your bonded item allows you to cast any one of your spells known (unlike a wizard’s bonded item, which allows him to cast any one spell in his spellbook). **This ability does not allow you to have both a familiar and a bonded item.**

If you make a Wizard x/Sorcerer Y with the arcane bloodline for Sorcerer, you have an Arcane Bond level of X + Y. If you chose to have a familiar, it would have a level equal to your character level in this case, for the purposes of determining its abilities. Similarly, if you had chosen a bonded object it would be counted as your character level for the purposes of determining what item creation feats you can use to add abilities to your bonded item.